# Getting the user’s Facebook list of friends

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After being able to create a small iOS app that logs in to Facebook. I would like this app to get the user’s list of friends.

Though I browsed the internet for a while and tried various approach I did not succeed to get what I wanted.

In the viewDidLoad method I use this code to start with:

```
loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_friends"]];
```

And then I implement the loginViewFetchedUserInfo: user:  method this way:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              NSLog(@“Result: %@",result);
                          }];
}
```

When I execute the app I get this result:

```
Result: {
    data =     (
    );
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 267;
    }; }
```

But what I really want is a list of the friends with their names …etc…
All the things I tried for that didn’t work. Though I suppose the solution must be simple.

I also used code like this in the method above ….. but with no luck:

```
NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
```

One more point, here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends one can read:

> This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login)
>   the app making the request.

But the result I get (267) does not match this statement. It (267) is the number of friends the user has on Facebook, which is in fact what I am interested in.

I hope someone has something to say to put me on the right track and make things clearer.

Comment: total_number will be the total number of friends. But data will only contain the one that are using your app

Comment: OK. That makes the result I get clear.
How do I get the result I want?
I am interested in the friends regardless of whether they have used the app or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Facebook's 2.x SDK upgrade they have tightened up access to information in the "Open Graph API."
Under [**Permissions That Do Not Require Review**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1)

> App friends. This optional permission grants your app the ability to read a list of friends who also use your app.

You get automatic access to any friends that already use your app (per its Facebook ID.)
You will have to request [*Extended Permissions*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-extended) if you want to access the list of *all* a user's friends. That means going through Facebook's [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) process which can be quite challenging (and annoying.)
Frankly, I am not even sure that it is possible to use the new Open Graph API to get the user's entire friend list.

Comment: From looking at Facebook's Graph API [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends/) the only entry for friends: `GET /v2.1/{user-id-a}/friends/{user-id-b}` specifically states "This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request."

Comment: It is understandable that they want to put some limitations. Nevertheless some apps have no meaning without an access to the complete list of friends. I guess I'll have to forget about this app idea I had in mind ... or go to the hard review process :)