# Facebook SDk3 how can i get the Facebook all friend list in my tableview and also i want to write some text on the particular friend

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**how can i get the Facebook all friend list in my iOS Application tableview and also  i want to write some text on the particular friend**

I'm using Facebook latest sdk

code :

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
    parameters:nil
    HTTPMethod:@"GET"
    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphUser> result, NSError *error) {
        /* handle the result */
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
}];
```

Comment: posting data on friends wall

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the user’s Facebook list of friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394874/getting-the-user-s-facebook-list-of-friends)

Answer (score 0):

With Facebook SDK 3.0 you can do this:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              NSDictionary* result,
                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
    }
}];
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: thanks hermit for your answer. but still it is not showing the friends details it giving the total count of the friends.

Comment: I'm using Graph API v2.2